# google spreadsheet api return empty last cell - python -

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, google-python-api

if spreadsheet is

```
    A | B | C
 1  1 |
 2  1 | 2 | 
 3  1 | 2 | 3
 4  1 |   | 3
```

this function from api google spreadsheet

```
self.service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=self.sheet,
                                                    range='{0}!{1}'.format(wstitle, a1range),
                                                    majorDimension=major_dimension=DIMENSIONS['ROWS'],
                                                    valueRenderOption=VALUE_RENDER_OPTION['FORMATTED'],
                                                    dateTimeRenderOption=DATETIME_RENDER_OPTION['FORMATTED']).execute()
```

return

```
[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,'',3]
```

is possible to return empty cells?
e.g.

```
 [1,'',''],[1,2,''],[1,2,3],[1,'',3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheetsv4 ignores empty cells and does not say that the cell's value is null.

It says in the docs that [empty rows and columns are omitted](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/reading#read_a_single_range_with_rendering_options):

> Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted.

I would suggest that you assign a dummy data/letter/symbol that represents your empty cells so that when you encounter this data/letter/symbol when you do a check using the "GET" method, you can interpret it as empty cell.

Related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442634/googlesheet-apiv4-getting-empty-cells/38471000#38471000).